# How to create a function and apply for each row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, function, if-statement

I have a somewhat-complex function that I am having difficulty writing. Essentially, I have a df that stores medical records and I need to identify the first site that a person goes to after their discharge date (I wish it was simple as choosing the first location after the initial stay, but it's not). The df is grouped by `ID`.

There are 3 options: (1) within a group, if any of the rows have a `begin_date` that matches the first rows `end_date`, return that location as the first site (if there are two rows that meet this condition, either are correct). (2) if the first option does not exist, then if there is an instance that the patient had `location` 'Health', then return 'Health'. (3) else, if conditions 1 and 2 do not exist, then return 'Home'

df

```
ID    color  begin_date    end_date     location
1     red    2017-01-01    2017-01-07   initial
1     green  2017-01-05    2017-01-07   nursing
1     blue   2017-01-07    2017-01-15   rehab
1     red    2017-01-11    2017-01-22   Health
2     red    2017-02-22    2017-02-26   initial
2     green  2017-02-26    2017-02-28   nursing
2     blue   2017-02-26    2017-02-28   rehab
3     red    2017-03-11    2017-03-22   initial
4     red    2017-04-01    2017-04-07   initial
4     green  2017-04-05    2017-04-07   nursing
4     blue   2017-04-10    2017-04-15   Health
```

finial result I am appending to a different df:

```
ID    first_site
1     rehab
2     nursing
3     home
4     Health
```

My approach is to write a function with these conditions, then use `apply()` to iterate over each row.

```
def conditions(x):
    if x['begin_date'].isin(x['end_date'].iloc[[0]]).any():
        return x['location'] 
    elif df[df['Health']] == True:
        return 'Health'
    else:
        return 'Home'

final = pd.DateFrame()
final['first'] = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: conditions(x))
```

I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Comment: Your function returns one value for each ID, whereas your original dataframe has a number of rows for each id. That's why the indices are incompatible. You can try to store the return of your groupby and apply process into a different structure (in which you have the id value and the return value of your groupby/apply), and then use that to fill the 'first' column in your dataframe (for example, by doing a left merge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need:

```
def conditions(x):
    #compare each group first
    val = x.loc[x['begin_date'] == x['end_date'].iloc[0], 'location']
    #if at least one match (not return empty `Series` get first value)
    if not val.empty:
        return val.iloc[0]
    #check if value Health
    elif (x['location']  == 'Health').any():
        return 'Health'
    else:
        return 'Home'

final = df.groupby('ID').apply(conditions).reset_index(name='first_site')
print (final)
   ID first_site
0   1      rehab
1   2    nursing
2   3       Home
3   4     Health
```

---

If need new column remove `reset_index` and add [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) or use solution from comment, thank you @Oriol Mirosa:

```
final = df.groupby('ID').apply(conditions)
df['first_site'] = df['ID'].map(final)
print (df)
    ID  color begin_date   end_date location first_site
0    1    red 2017-01-01 2017-01-07  initial      rehab
1    1  green 2017-01-05 2017-01-07  nursing      rehab
2    1   blue 2017-01-07 2017-01-15    rehab      rehab
3    1    red 2017-01-11 2017-01-22   Health      rehab
4    2    red 2017-02-22 2017-02-26  initial    nursing
5    2  green 2017-02-26 2017-02-28  nursing    nursing
6    2   blue 2017-02-26 2017-02-28    rehab    nursing
7    3    red 2017-03-11 2017-03-22  initial       Home
8    4    red 2017-04-01 2017-04-07  initial     Health
9    4  green 2017-04-05 2017-04-07  nursing     Health
10   4   blue 2017-04-10 2017-04-15   Health     Health
```

---

`Apply` obviously is slow, if performance is important use:

```
#first filter by end date for each group
end = df.groupby('ID')['end_date'].transform('first')
df1 = df[(df['begin_date'] == end)]

#filter Health rows
df2 = df[(df['location'] == 'Health')]
#get filtered df together and remove duplicates, last reindex by all ID
#values for append missing ID rows 
df3 = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
        .drop_duplicates('ID')
        .set_index('ID')['location']
        .reindex(df['ID'].unique(), fill_value='Home')
        .reset_index(name='first_site'))
print (df3)
   ID first_site
0   1      rehab
1   2    nursing
2   3       Home
3   4     Health
```

Comment: Exactly. As I said in my comment above, in order to get the final df, you just need a left merge: `pd.merge(df, final, how='left, on='ID')`

Comment: @OriolMirosa - Exactly. Or use `map` :)